# Test equality of an API which is present in different languages

Tags: java, c, api, testing, equality

How would you tackle the following problem?

I've got an API which validates tokens (which are just simple XML files). So the API specifies a bunch of validation methods like `validateTime(String tokenPath)`, `validateFileHash(String tokenPath)` or `validateSomthingElse(String tokenPath)`.

The API is already implemented in two different languages, Java and C. My task is to make sure, that both versions **behave the same**. So if Java throws a `TokenExpiredException` after invoking `validateTime("expiredToken.xml")`, C should return a corresponding error value (in this case a predefined `-4` for TOKEN_EXPIRED).

The good old approach would be to write Unit/Integration-tests in both languages. However, this would require double the effort as I would have to implement essentially the same Tests in Java and in C.

My idea was to define a XML-Schema for TestCases which would look something like this.

```
<!-- TestCases.xml -->
<testcase>
  <tokenpath>expiredToken.xml</tokenpath>
  <apiMethod>validateTime</apiMethod>
  <expectationJava>TokenExpiredException</expectationJava>
  <expectationC>-4</expectationC>
</testcase>

<testcase>
  ...
</testcase>
```

Furthermore, I would build a small Java tool to parse TestCases.xml and directly invoke both API versions (using JNI for C) to match the outcome to the preset expectations.

Do you think this is a feasible plan, or is it better to do the old approach? Are there Frameworks to deal with this kind of tasks or is it a smelly idea to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is feasible, what would be even better is if you can take advantage of some existing [data driven testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_testing) frameworks. This way you don't need to do the legwork of parsing inputs, running test cases and asserting outputs.

Here's an example of how to drive Java tests through JUnit + an excel spreadsheet containing the data: http://www.wakaleo.com/component/content/article/241

I didn't see one immediately, but hopefully you can find something similar for C.